# Complex transitive complementation

Tags: descriptive-grammar

Would it sound appropriately if to relay a sentence: "We expected him to make a good job of that" in the following ways:

1. We expected for him to make a good job of that.
2. We expected it for him to make a good job of that.

Comment: The first is wrong because "expected" in this sense requires a direct object. The second might be ok if punctuated "We expected it, for him to make a good job of that", where "for him to make a good job of that" is explaining what "it" refers to (compare "It would be helpful for him to make a good job of that.") - I'm not sure what the precise grammar term for this is and can't immediately see it in definitions of "for" but it certainly sounds valid.

Comment: Thank you! And how would you take in the modification of the pattern: "We liked for him to make a good job of that"?

Comment: Neither 1. nor 2. is grammatical. Why are you seeking alternants for your original example?

Comment: @BillJ It is interesting for me from a linguistic point of view. Some native speakers easily accept (as I can see in the aforecited comment) what may seem of marginal (if at all) acceptability to the others. And a pattern "We liked (it) for him to make a good job of that" is being perceived by native speakers as relevant to live English (as far as I can judge).